# How to use Method projects.agent.export of DialogFlow for export agent?

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, python-requests, dialogflow-es

I'm trying to access to a DialogFlow Agent Information using python library requests, using [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent/export?hl=es&apix_params=%7B%22parent%22%3A%22projects%2Fnewagent-1-oeneai%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D#request-body) for support.

But I think the doc is not fully explained.

Can someone give me a simple use example for this API, specifying headers, body, and parameters of POST request?

Answer (score 1):

On the left side of your screen, in "Try this API" segment, you might be able to find a button, next to the closing cross, which opens a popup.

By clicking you could see a popup which among other options shows:

```
curl --request POST \
  'https://dialogflow.googleapis.com/v2/projects/YOUR_PROJECT_NAME/agent:export?key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"agentUri":"agentUri_ID"}' \
  --compressed
```

As you can see, you only need to hit the correct endpoint with your API_KEY, and adding your ACCESS TOKEN in the header and the agentUri_ID, the only requested string parameter regardless authentication.

*agentUri:  Required. The Google Cloud Storage URI to export the agent to. The format of this URI must be gs:///. If left unspecified, the serialized agent is returned inline.*

Comment: I see (and thank you, by the way), but I don't know how implement directly using python3.x (Suppose is with requests library) or what instructions. Do you have some docs for reading of StackOverflow answers about what I need to do?